# Questions encountered dealing with logistic regression using python

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression

Right now i'm trying to solve the tasks from the ML course by Andrew Ng.
I'm using python to do the logistic regression, but the result is quite confusing for me. And there's something wrong when using scipy.opt function

I'm asked to do classification by using logistic regression. The functions for calculating cost and gradient are:

So instead of using opt function provided in scipy, i want to insist on gradient-descent to update the parameter, as taught in the previous tutorial.

But when i use different learning rate(alpha), the cost changes differently.

Here's the result when alpha=0.0001,iteration=400000

[cost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t26zI.png)
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foy8l.png)

And...Here's the result when alpha=0.01,iteration=200000

[cost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFXh4.png)
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2PeH.png)

Seems like this chaos-like result is hard to explained for me, although the final result is acceptable.
Is there any explanation for this situation?

And  something went wrong when using scipy.opt
Seems like this chaos-like result is hard to explained for me, although the final result is acceptable.
Is there any explanation for this situation?

```
m,n=data.shape 
X=data[:,0:n-1]
y=data[:,-1:]
theta=np.array([[0] for i in range(n)],dtype=np.float64)
print(X.shape,y.shape,theta.shape)

# OUT:(100, 2) (100, 1) (3, 1)

X=np.concatenate((np.array([[1] for i in range(m)]),X),axis=1)

def sigmoid(z):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-z))
def h(X,theta):
    return sigmoid(X@theta)
def calculate_cost(X,y,theta):
    first=-y.T @ np.log(h(X,theta)+1e-5)  
    second=(1-y).T@np.log(1-h(X,theta)+1e-5)   
    return 1/m*(first-second)[0][0]
def gradient(X,y,theta):
    return  1/m*(X.T@(h(X,theta)-y)).T

result = opt.fmin_tnc(func=calculate_cost, x0=theta, fprime=gradient, args=(X, y))
```

There is a ValueError through out:

```
Cell In[5], line 4, in h(X, theta)
      3 def h(X,theta):
----> 4     return sigmoid(X@theta)

ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 100 is different from 3)
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `fmin_tnc` gives the `x0` parameter as first parameter to the function it tries to optimize. To solve this, just use `theta` as first parameter for both `calculate_cost` and `gradient`.
I also fixed some missmatches which crashed the code for me (`return 1/m*(first-second)[0][0]` -> `return 1/m*(first-second)[0]` and `1/m*(X.T@(h(X,theta)-y)).T, axis=0` -> `np.mean(1/m*(X.T@(h(X,theta)-y)).T, axis=0)`), but you'll have to take a look if it is useful to e.g. take the mean for the gradient.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize as opt

data = np.random.rand(100, 3)

m,n=data.shape
X=data[:,0:n-1]
y=data[:,-1:]
theta=np.array([[0] for i in range(n)],dtype=np.float64)
print(X.shape,y.shape,theta.shape)

# OUT:(100, 2) (100, 1) (3, 1)

X=np.concatenate((np.array([[1] for i in range(m)]),X),axis=1)

def sigmoid(z):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-z))
def h(X,theta):
    return sigmoid(X@theta)
def calculate_cost(theta, X,y):
    first=-y.T @ np.log(h(X,theta)+1e-5)  
    second=(1-y).T@np.log(1-h(X,theta)+1e-5)   
    return 1/m*(first-second)[0]
def gradient(theta, X,y):
    return np.mean(1/m*(X.T@(h(X,theta)-y)).T, axis=0)

result = opt.fmin_tnc(func=calculate_cost, x0=theta, fprime=gradient, args=(X, y))
```

Comment: By the way, I have finished my test just now. Instead of np.mean(1/m*(X.T@(h(X,theta)-y)).T, axis=0), using np.squeeze() function also works. The very big problem is that the fmin_tnc function somehow CHANGED THE SHAPE of input. The theta parameter is initiallized as a column vector, whose shape is (3,1). But through the test(by inserting PRINT function in calculate_cost function and gradient function), I notice that the shape of theta becomes (3,). This will lead to a completely wrong answer, since  
         h(X,theta)-y      ( [(100,) -(100,1)])     becomes  (100,100) output.

Comment: And the initial value of theta also matters. if intial value for theta is [1,1,1], the opt function fails, but gradient descent still works!